# MongoDB aggregation from few operations

Tags: mongodb

Every user in our system (Like Facebook and twitter) has an option to add other users to his predefined lists like: *"Favorites", "Follow", "Blocked", "Closed Friends". Than, we want to allow him to search the list, filter and see commutative data from all the above list. for example:

```
UserA {
   IsFollow: 1,
   IsFavorite: 0
   ...
   IsBlocked: 0
}
```

We also want to keep some additional information when user adding another user to one of the above list such addingDate.

Option One is to manage different collections like "Favorites", "Follow", "Blocked", "Closed Friends"

Option Two - to manage one collection like "Relations" and keep all the data on that collection without the needs of using lookup...

Option Three - Use option One but create a flat collection with all the relevant data from each table (RabbitMQ, transaction update, etc).

Since I'm new in MongoDB (I'm migrating the system from MS SQL), I'm wondering what is the best approach for high scale system.

Comment: DocumentDB is not MongoDB - which one are you actually using?

Comment: are you using mongoosejs?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks, I updated the question. i am using MongoDB.

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren - Yes. I am using Mongoose as part of LoopbackJS.

Comment: do you know mongoose-autopopulate? Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go with option 2, where all the keys will be present in one document.

MongoDB recommends a schema design where all the data are embedded into a single document. They claim that this will lead to less read-write operations to DB and faster CRUD operations compared to the relational mapping approach.

But, there is a catch here. The data should be embedded in a single document only if the relations are `One-to-One`, `One-to-Few`, or `One-to-Many`.

**DO NOT GO WITH DOCUMENT EMBEDDING APPROACH IF YOUR DATA MAPPING RELATION IS `One-to-Squillions`.** I recommend you to read [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

The reason why I am not recommending Option-1 to have a separate collection is you will have to make more requests to a DB for each and every collection linkage. Although the `$lookup` stage is fast, it is not as efficient compared to the embedding approach.

As far as option 3 goes, it's a viable approach (If you use transactions properly and effectively), but it adds up complexity in the coding side.

I have personally used both Option-1 & Option-2 approaches, and option-1 has always left the AWS-EC2 instance running MongoDB to higher CPU and RAM usage. As far as option-2 goes, I have a collection that has almost 1000 array elements (With key indexed) and 15K keys in each records (I am not joking) and MongoDB had no issues processing it. Just make sure that you use the `Projection` of return documents everywhere.

So, go for Option-2 as a standard approach and Option-3 for `One-to-Squillions` relation mapping.

For referencing two or more collections, make sure that you use MongoDB generated `ObjectId` instead of your own custom referencing since have seen a minor performance impact on using multi-document relation-mapping other than ObjectId (Even if that particular key is indexed)

Hope this helps. Reach me out if you have additional queries